# Python - check if function argument is dict and have values

Tags: python

Here i have below function with list

```
def prdata(somelist):
    if all(x != None for x in list1.values()): 
    #check list have values 
    #but gives me error for list1 AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'values'
        for x in somelist:
            print(somelist[x])
    else:
        # print("invalid dict")
```

my input might be set or dict like below

```
list1 = {"a", "b", "c"}
prdata(list1)

list2 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
prdata(list1)
```

how do i check inside function and raise proper error

Comment: The first one is a `set`, not a `dict`. Hence they have different methods.

Comment: My professor never mentioned that, how can check the argument passed to my function whether it is a set or dict

Comment: sets do not have a `values()` attribute

Comment: @Srinivas You can use `type(<elem>)` function to check if its set or dict.

Comment: if isinstance(list1, set):

Comment: You should *know* what kind of values you're working with/expect. You also wouldn't substitute an `int` for a `dict` or any other random value and still expect your code to work.

Comment: sorry, i just updated my question that i don't know my input whether its a `set` or `dict`

Comment: your new question has already been answered in the comments section, if your input is always set or dictionary, you could also create an AttributeError exception and handle it properly...

Comment: type(somelist) == set, is that it?

Answer (score 0):

list1 is a set rather than a dict. To test membership in a set, just use "x in list1".

Answer (score 0):

list1 is set where as list2 is dictionary

You need to change code in case of list1 as follows -

```
list1 = {"a", "b", "c"}
all(x != None for x in list1)
```

This returns True

Answer (score 0):

your code

```
list1 = {"a", "b", "c"}
```

this is not list nor dictionary. this is [set](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

```
all(x != None for x in list1.values())
```

sets does not have values method. Perhaps you can direct iterate over set elements.